# draw dotted semicircles with subtler dots

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

I want to draw some semicircle. Most of them are dotted (except three of them). Now i want to draw those dots much closer and much 'subtler' to each other. So it doesn't look like a piece of dots, but like circles they are.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]

% A clipped circle is drawn
\begin{scope}
    \clip (-1.5,0) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
    \draw (-0.95,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw [dotted] (-0.793,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw [dotted] (-0.636,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw [dotted] (-0.479,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw [dotted] (-0.322,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw (-0.13,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw [dotted] (0.008,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw [dotted] (0.149,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw [dotted] (0.306,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw [dotted] (0.463,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw (0.69,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw [dotted] (0.777,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw [dotted] (0.934,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw (-1.5,0) -- (18,0);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Section 15.3.2 of the pgf manual, Dash Patterns, holds the information that you need. There are several pre-defined patterns of varying density. For your purposes, `[dotted]`, `[densely dotted]`, `[loosely dotted]` are relevant. You can define your own pattern with a METAFONT-like syntax such as: `[dash pattern=on 2pt off 3pt on 4pt off 4pt]` This gives a dash-dot pattern, “draw 2pt, then leave out 3pt, then draw 4pt once more, then leave out 4pt again, repeat”. Manual to be found at: http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your own `dotted` style. `densely dotted`, for example, has the settings `[dash pattern=on \pgflinewidth off 1pt]`, so we can create a new style `\tikzstyle{my dotted}=[line width=.2pt,dash pattern=on \pgflinewidth off \pgflinewidth]`. This will have the effect of closer dots and finer line width.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

% Redefine densely dotted 
\tikzstyle{my dotted}=[line width=.2pt,dash pattern=on \pgflinewidth off \pgflinewidth] % off 1pt

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]

% A clipped circle is drawn
\begin{scope}
    \clip (-1.5,0) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
    \draw (-0.95,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw [my dotted] (-0.793,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw [my dotted] (-0.636,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw [my dotted] (-0.479,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw [my dotted] (-0.322,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw (-0.13,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw [my dotted] (0.008,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw [my dotted] (0.149,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw [my dotted] (0.306,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw [my dotted] (0.463,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw (0.69,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw [my dotted] (0.777,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw [my dotted] (0.934,0) circle(0.4);
    \draw (-1.5,0) -- (18,0);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]